# When click a link to lead to a new .php page, the link doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css, web

As the title states, when I click a link on the submenu within the page (the one in the content area, not the header) the links don't actually follow to their respective .php pages.  I've checked everything out twice and I can't find the issue.   Any clues?

Thanks!

Page of reference: http://rdesignmedia.com/cherokee/commercialindustrial.php

Comment: My mistake -  I figured everyone just did "inspect element" in the page.   One sec! :)

Comment: How do I add code so that it formats correctly?

Comment: You appear to have JavaScript conflicts. Disabling all JS scripts on the page makes the links work.

Comment: Edit your question, and paste in the code. Then highlight it all and press Ctrl-K (or Command-K on mac) - this is the same as clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: Stuart is right.  I can see some 50 odd errors in my Web Console

Comment: I went and starting get of some JS Scripts and found it to be this one.

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

But if I get rid of that, my images don't line up properly anymore...

Comment: @MikeL You don't have to get rid of it. Just figure out which line causes the issue, and remove (or rewrite) that.

Comment: @StuartWagner  -  I'm trying my best at the moment, it's just hard. I received this website second hand from someone else and was tasked to finish it. This was one of the issues I can't figure out :(

Comment: @MikeL I believe I found the problem. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your JavaScript files, `script.js`, includes a click event listener that is breaking your anchors. See lines 53-70:

```
// Isotope Filter
$filter.find('a').click(function(){

    ...

    return false;
});
```

If you remove the `return false;` your links should work again. The problem is that `return false;` instructs the client to prevent normal execution of the click event on the given element (i.e. the anchors don't navigate).

Comment: I'm curious.  What clues led you to find that specific line?  Just for future reference.

Comment: @MikeL I knew it was being caused by JavaScript from my earlier test of disabling all JS on the page, and you had mentioned above that you figured out what file it was. So I searched that file for any reference to `click` in order to see if there was an event listener attached to those anchors. Luckily, the very first occurrence was exactly the listener I was expecting, and sure enough, there was a `return false;` in it. So I commented that out and tested it against your page. When that worked, I came back here and posted my findings.

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the walkthrough.  So would there be any reason that someone would code that to return false; ? for whatever reason?

Comment: Sure, it's not uncommon. Just potentially dangerous. Check this out: https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/